# Why is SQL Server Keeping This Table Variable's Data Between Loops?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

When I run the below script, SQL server keeps the `@tblInstance` table's data in between loop iterations and adds to it. I thought a table variable is literally a variable and that it wouldn't have scope outside the loop?

```
declare @tblSummary as table (...)

declare @tblIterator table (...)
insert into @tblIterator
select *
from RealTable
where ...

declare @index as int
declare @rowCount as int
declare @id as int
set @index = 1
set @rowCount = (select max([row]) from @tblIterator)

while @index <= @rowCount
begin

set @id = null

set @id = (select top 1 id from @tblIterator tblIterator where tblIterator.[row] = @index)


declare @tblInstance as table(...)
insert into @tblInstance exec SomeProc @id

insert into @tblSummary
select @id, sum(x), ...
from @tblInstance tblInstance

set @index = (select @index + 1)
end

select * from @tblSummary order by id
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have block scope. Variables last until the end of the batch.

Comment: Ah thanks. Good to know.